# What does "proportional" mean?

Tags: arithmetic, definition

I used to think of $\propto$ as indicating the one quantity is proportional to the other, with possibly an additive constant involved, i.e. $f(x) \propto g(x)$ if $f(x) = ag(x) + b$. Is that reasonable, or does $\propto$ mostly requires $b=0$? Wikipedia seems to refer only to a multiplicative constant.

Comment: I guess the standard use of the proportionality symbol requires $b=0$.

Comment: "Linear relationship" has this confusion sometimes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between proportional and directly proportional in differential equations?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2469258/what-is-the-difference-between-proportional-and-directly-proportional-in-differe)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, proportional means related only by a multiplicative constant.  When $g(x)$ doubles, so does $f(x)$.  If $b \neq 0$ this will not be true.