# What is the difference between proportional and directly proportional in differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> **Example 1:** A pond has surface area of 10 m$^2$. The area $A$ of weeds present at time $t$ months is such that the rate at which the area is increasing is proportional to the product of the area of pond covered by the weeds and the area of the pond not covered by the weeds.

The answer provided on how to form a differential equation for the above is:
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}A}{\mathrm{d}t} = kA(10-A). $$

However, shouldn't it be
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}A}{\mathrm{d}t} = kA(10-A)+c?$$
The answer provided seems to be taking for granted that it's directly proportional. Most of the provided solutions I come across when doing differential equations questions all seem to take for granted that its direct proportionality when the question only states that they are proportionate.

Is it just me getting something wrong? I've always learnt when deriving relationships in physics that there is an important distinction between the two.

Comment: Maybe I should have just phrased the entire question as is y proportional to x in y=mx+c where c is not 0?

Comment: For a long time, I too shared your misconception that $y$ is proportional to $x$ with $y=f(x)$ means that the line need not pass through the origin. Although searching Physics Stack Exchange doesn't support this notion, it's likely that we did indirectly osmose it from certain Physics/Psychology/science texts. But of course, framing just *directly proportional* but not *inversely proportional* as a special case of *proportional* is inconsistent! $\quad$ Anyhow, one definition: "$y$ is proportional to $x$" ⟺  for some $C$ that is independent of $x$ (and of $y$) and not identically zero, $y=Cx.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "usual" definition of the term *proportional*, as used in early mathematics (such as calculus, differential equations, and other areas where we don't worry about numbers which might not be real), is usually something like:

> **Definition:**  Suppose that $x$ and $y$ are real variables.  Then
>
> - $y$ is (*directly*) *proportional* to $x$ if there is a constant $k\ne 0$ such that $y = kx$, and
> - $y$ is *inversely proportional* to $x$ if there is a constant $k\ne 0$ such that $y = k/x$.

This is, for example, the definition given in *Thomas' Calculus* and Sisson's *Precalculus* (the two texts which my department has chosen to teach these courses out of, hence I have them easily to hand).

Thus the term *proportional* is simply a shorthand for *directly proportional*.

It is very possible that the terms *proportional* and *directly proportional* are understood to mean different things in some other context (the question suggests, for example, that there are contexts in physics where they would be understood to be different).  However, the usual convention in mathematics is the one given above.

---

A note on the problem given:  consider the long-term behaviour of a pond with weeds in it.  The model
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}A}{\mathrm{d}t} = kA(10-A) $$
has two equilibria:  $A = 0$ and $A = 10$, which correspond to states in which the pond has no weeds at all, and in which the pond is completely covered by weeds.  The only reasonable values for $A$ are between $0$ and $10$ (inclusive; there cannot be a negative area covered by weeds, and the area of the pond covered by weeds cannot be greater than the area of the pond).  For any choice of $A$ in this range, the derivative is positive, and the area of the pond covered by weeds will increase until it is completely covered.

All of this makes sense, from a physical point of view.

Now consider the alternative model,
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}A}{\mathrm{d}t} = kA(10-A)+c.$$
If $c\ne 0$, then this model has no equilibria.  If $c$ is positive, then the area of the pond covered by weeds will continue to increase, even after the pond is completely covered.  This doesn't really make physical sense.  On the other hand, if $c$ is negative, then a pond with no weeds in it will have a decreasing area of weeds, leading to a negative area, which again doesn't make sense.

The equation with the $+c$ also suffers from the fact that it is no longer *autonomous*—we expect that the coverage of the pond by weeds should only depend on (1) how much of the pond is covered at some specific time $T$, and (2) how much time has elapsed since $T$.

For example, suppose that we note on Day 0 that the pond is half covered by weeds, and then on Day 10 it is three quarters covered by weeds.  We would expect that if the pond is half covered by weeds on Day 123, it should be three quarters covered on Day 133.  The first model has this property, while the second does not.  This is, again, problematic from the point of view of a physical model:  suppose that you and I both start examining this pond on the same day, but I start counting days at 1, and you start at 0.  Under the first model, we will both make the same predictions; under the second model, we'll get different results.

Therefore, even if we grant that *proportional* might be an ambiguous term, the only sensible interpretation of that term in this context is *directly proportional*.

Answer (score 1):

When one of these problems simply says "proportional", that is short for "directly proportional". If the quantities were inversely proportional, then the word "inversely", or something equivalent to it, would be required for a correct statement.

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no such constant in inverse proportionality  ... like what occurs in a linear relation.

- **Directly proportional** *and* $ \text{in common parlance}$  a.k.a.  **proportional**  $\quad y=m \cdot x$
- Linear, but not directly proportional $y=m \cdot x+c,~ c\ne 0 $
- Inversely proportional $~~ x \cdot  y = c$

*Related*: Lens formula in Optics gives an inverse relation between object/image distances $ (u,v) $ but only when focal length is removed from each. (Gauss)
$$ (u-f)\cdot (v-f) = f^2; \to \frac{1}{u}+ \frac{1}{v}= \frac{1}{f}; $$